# Enable orphan words feature for NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsmutableattributedstring

The default behavior for UILabel is that it prevents orphan words to appear solely on a separate line. ie: if word wrapping happen to keep 1 word alone at the last line. iOS will prevent that by sending a word from the line before it, having two words in the last line.

The problem is that this feature doesn't work by default with `NSMutableAttributedString`. how can I enable it?

**Sample:**

```
var string = customField?.title ?? ""
    
if customField?.required == true {
    string += " *"
} else {
    string += " (\(getLocalizedString(localizedKey: .optional)))"
}
            
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    style.lineBreakStrategy = .standard
}

let att = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string, attributes: [.paragraphStyle: style])
    
titleLabel.attributedText = att
```

Have in mind I am forced to use `NSMutableAttributedString` for other reasons. 2 labels won't work for me.

[image]

Comment: let me try. but doesn't that prevent wrapping?

Comment: Sorry, bad suggestion. Answer incoming.

Comment: I updated question. it still not working even without setting different attributes for the *

Comment: One option is to use a non-editable non-scrollable `UITextView` instead of a `UILabel` ... however, it's not clear (to me) where you are getting an orphan from word wrapping?

Comment: @hasan -- oh, are you saying you need your text to end with "lastword *" and the asterisk (red in attributed string) is wrapping onto a line by itself? and you need that last word to wrap with it?

Comment: Ya I need the asterisk not to be alone by itself on a separate line. It turned out the problem wasn't with attributedtext. it still work. but the problem is when u have a constraint (trailing for example) to another label that layout at runtime because have dynamic text. the orphan words feature doesn't work. therefore the asterisk some times will be alone in a line. I ended up using \u{00A0} instead of space before the *. which is uni code for unbreakable space. ie the * and the word before it will be treated as 1 word. can't be broken to two lines.

Comment: @hasan - yep... using non-break-space character is the solution I was going to give you :)

Comment: @DonMag Ty anyway. you can add it as solution. I can accept it. but add my explanation to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per OP's comments...

The issue is not with Attributed Text, as the same thing happens with "normal" text.

With iOS 11 (may have been 10), Apple changed UIKit to prevent orphans when a `UILabel` wraps to ***two lines of text***. Orphans are still allowed with **more than** two lines:

[image]

`A` was prior to iOS 11... `B` is current... `C` is current with more than two lines...

Note the `D` example -- I don't have the Xcode beta installed, but based on other comments I've seen it appears that in **iOS 16** the "no orphan" rule will also be applied when the text wraps to more than two lines.

So... a way to solve your issue is to use a "non-break-space" character between the last word and the asterisk (instead of a plain space).

Here's a quick test:

```
class WrapTestVC: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 4
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(stackView)

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 320.0),
        ])
        
        var noteLabel: UILabel!
        var testLabel: UILabel!
    
        let noteFont: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 14.0)
        
        noteLabel = UILabel()
        noteLabel.font = noteFont
        noteLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        noteLabel.text = "Just enough to fit:"
    
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(noteLabel)
        
        testLabel = UILabel()
        testLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        testLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        testLabel.attributedText = sampleAttrString(method: 0)

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(testLabel)
        
        stackView.setCustomSpacing(20.0, after: testLabel)
        
        noteLabel = UILabel()
        noteLabel.font = noteFont
        noteLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        noteLabel.text = "Using a space char:"
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(noteLabel)
        
        testLabel = UILabel()
        testLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        testLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        testLabel.attributedText = sampleAttrString(method: 1)
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(testLabel)
        
        stackView.setCustomSpacing(20.0, after: testLabel)
        
        noteLabel = UILabel()
        noteLabel.font = noteFont
        noteLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        noteLabel.text = "Using a non-break-space char:"
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(noteLabel)
        
        testLabel = UILabel()
        testLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        testLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        testLabel.attributedText = sampleAttrString(method: 2)
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(testLabel)

        stackView.setCustomSpacing(20.0, after: testLabel)
        
        noteLabel = UILabel()
        noteLabel.font = noteFont
        noteLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        noteLabel.text = "Although, iOS 16 may give:"
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(noteLabel)
        
        testLabel = UILabel()
        testLabel.backgroundColor = .yellow
        testLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        testLabel.attributedText = sampleAttrString(method: 3)
        
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(testLabel)
        
        stackView.setCustomSpacing(20.0, after: testLabel)
        

    }

    func sampleAttrString(method: Int) -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        let fontA: UIFont = .systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .bold)
        
        let attsA: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
            .font: fontA,
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
        ]
        
        let attsB: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
            .font: fontA,
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
        ]
        
        var partOne = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "If the label has enough text so it wraps to more than two lines, UIKit will allow a last word orphan.", attributes: attsA)
        
        var partTwo: NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString()
        
        switch method {
        case 0:
            ()
        case 1:
            partTwo = NSAttributedString(string: " *", attributes: attsB)
        case 2:
            partTwo = NSAttributedString(string: "\u{a0}*", attributes: attsB)
        case 3:
            partOne = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "If the label has enough text so it wraps to more than two lines, UIKit will allow a last\nword orphan.", attributes: attsA)
            partTwo = NSAttributedString(string: "\u{a0}*", attributes: attsB)
        default:
            ()
        }
        
        partOne.append(partTwo)
        
        return partOne
    }

}
```

Output:

[image]

So... you'll want to test that with iOS 16, and, if that's the case, you may need to do a version check to determine wether to add a plain space or a non-break-space.

Answer (score 3):

It is a change by Apple since iOS11 (as answered by @DonMag) to prevent orphaned word in the last line.

If your production only support iOS13.0+, setting the lineBreakStrategy will set it back to the old style.

```
let label = UILabel()
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    label.lineBreakStrategy = NSParagraphStyle.LineBreakStrategy()
}
```

(One interesting thing is, I found this lineBreakStrategy also work on iOS 13.0+, even tho from [Apple's document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/3667730-linebreakstrategy) it mentioned iOS 14.0+.)

If you need to support older iOS version, you need to set the value of the `NSAllowsDefaultLineBreakStrategy` key when application launch, which I cannot find any document about it. I tested it worked on iOS 11 & 12, but not on iOS 13.0+.

```
// Setting the undocumented key NSAllowsDefaultLineBreakStrategy
UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "NSAllowsDefaultLineBreakStrategy")
```

So you might need both if your app support iOS 11.0+. Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [the `lineBreakStrategy` property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/3667730-linebreakstrategy) on `UILabel`, which helps control this behavior:

> When the label has an attributed string value, the system ignores the `textColor`, `font`, `textAlignment`, `lineBreakMode`, and `lineBreakStrategy` properties. Set the `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`, `NSFontAttributeName`, `alignment`, `lineBreakMode`, and `lineBreakStrategy` properties in the attributed string instead.

If you want to use a specific line break strategy, like [`.standard`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslinebreakstrategy/nslinebreakstrategystandard) ("The text system uses the same configuration of line-break strategies that it uses for standard UI labels. "), you will need to apply the attribute to the attributed string via a paragraph style:

```swift
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineBreakStrategy = .standard

let text = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: "long title with an asterisk at the end *",
    attributes: [.paragraphStyle: style]
)

titleLabel.attributedText = text
```

Depending on your text, it *may* also help to set [`allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsmutableparagraphstyle/1534136-allowsdefaulttighteningfortrunca) on the paragraph style because that may allow the text system to tighten the space between words on the last line of the string to get everything to fit. (I say *may* because this property controls truncation specifically, but it's possible that the text system can take it into account for wrapping as well.)

Comment: Wow, let me try that ty.

Comment: No, it didn't work. and actually this documentation is wrong I guess. The system doesn't ignore those things at all when u have attributed string. I always only set the attributes for the part of the string and keep the rest take the style from the UILabel it self !

Comment: @hasan Can you share the full code you've used to test this out? Specifically, depending on how you apply attributes to parts of the string, you may be overwriting the attributes that would allow this to work. (For example, if you use `setAttributes:` instead of `addAttributes:` for part of the range of the string.)

Comment: ok wait 10 seconds

Comment: @hasan I suspect that it's also possible that the text system doesn't consider `"*"` to be a word (because it contains no letters), so it treats the text differently from regular orphan words. If you apply this text as a plain string to the label, does it manage to avoid wrapping the last asterisk character then?

Comment: let me try it then with label.text

Comment: @hasan Depending on what you discover with just `label.text`: what if you append `"*"` instead of `" *"` so the text joins the last word itself?

Comment: That could be a solution if nothing worked. but maybe product manager will not like it.